# reading a csv file and printing out rows

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I have created a csv file with two columns - the subject and the modules.
and i want to print out all the modules for the same subject
the csv file looks like this [csvfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqRAu.png)
currently my code looks like:

```
import csv

subject = "Biology"
subject_module = []
with open("SubjectModules.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        subject_module_info = []
        subject, module = row
        while (row["Subject"] == subject):
            subject_module_info.append(module)
            subject_module.append(subject_module_info)
    
    print(subject_module)
```

the output is just [] with no modules stored, how would i fix it?

Comment: Please be sure to verify that your code looks like it should before you post it, since badly indented python code is invalid python code. You need to either indent the _entire_ code block by 4 spaces, or add three backticks (`) on the lines before and after your code [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: Please also provide a [mre]. Your code alone will not reproduce your problem because it depends on the SubjectModules.csv file. Please provide a sample of  your file (as formatted text, not a screenshot) that is representative of the entire file and will allow us to replicate the issue in our environments. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO

Comment: What do you expect this line does: `subject,module = row`? Why are you trying to unpack the dict? Have you found out what unpacking the dict gives you? When you overwrite `subject` with the result of unpacking the dict, do you think `subject` will _ever_ be equal to `row["Subject"]`? (in fact, you're lucky it isn't, because that would cause the `while row["Subject"]` == subject` loop to be _infinite!_) Do you really need that `while` loop? What flow-control statement checks a condition _only once?_ [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier by using **pandas**.

```
import pandas as pd
subject = "Biology"
df = pd.read_csv('./SubjectModules.csv')
df = df[df['Subject'] == subject]
module_list = df['Module'].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do may be less complicated than your sample code suggests.

For example, here is some code using a smaller sample version of your SubjectModules.csv file:

```py
import csv
subject = "Biology"
subject_module = []

with open ("SubjectModules.csv", newline = "") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
    print()

with open ("SubjectModules.csv", newline = "") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        if (row["Subject"] == subject):
            module = row["Module"]
            subject_module.append(module)

print(subject_module)
```

It gives this result:

```
{'Subject': 'Accounting', 'Module': 'foo1'}
{'Subject': 'Accounting', 'Module': 'foo2'}
{'Subject': 'Accounting', 'Module': 'foo3'}
{'Subject': 'Art and Design', 'Module': 'bar1'}
{'Subject': 'Art and Design', 'Module': 'bar2'}
{'Subject': 'Art and Design', 'Module': 'bar3'}
{'Subject': 'Art and Design', 'Module': 'bar4'}
{'Subject': 'Biology', 'Module': 'baz1'}
{'Subject': 'Biology', 'Module': 'baz2'}

['baz1', 'baz2']
```

It creates and prints a list of all the modules for the given subject ('Biology'). To do this, only some of the variables in your original code were required, and others have been eliminated.